# Conditional operator in Java

Tags: java, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

Executing the following program is producing the following result, please explain the reason why the value of sum is 120 and of price is 100.

```
double sum=10, price =100;
sum+=price>=100?price * 1.1 : price;
Syso(sum);
Syso(price);
```

The output is
120
100

Comment: Syso? Do you mean System.out.println?

Comment: (1) This reads like a homework question. (2) Syso doesn't exist. (3) Please show your own progress first.

Comment: condition is price either equal to or greater than 100 then multiply price by 1.1.here condition is true so sum=10(old sum)+110(price after multiply) so result is sum=120 but multiply price is not assign to price so it not change and show price=100

Answer (score 0):

```
expression ? value 1 : value 2
```

`if expression is true, result is value 1` (first condition)

`if expression is false ,result is value 2`（second condition）

Example:

```
x = 1, x > 10 ? x : 10
```

expression: `x > 10  => false`

value 1: `x`
value 2: `10`

result is `10`